# Get the position of X user in the ranking

Tags: sql

I have these tables

RANKING

```
+-----------+----------+
| id_users  |  points  |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 27       | //3rd
| 2         | 55       | //1st
| 3         | 9        | //5th
| 4         | 14       | //4th
| 5         | 38       | //2nd
+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to retrieve user's data along with its ranking position, filtering by id. So for example if I want info for id 3 I should get

```
+----------+--------|---------------+
| id_users | points | rank_position |
+----------+--------|---------------+
| 3        | 9      | 5             |
+----------+--------|---------------+
```

My query actually has the following:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points ASC) AS RowNum, 
    id_users 
FROM 
    RANKING
```

And I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ROW_NUMBER()`, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points ASC) AS RowNum
      FROM RANKING r
     ) r
WHERE id_users = 5;
```